# Please explain . ./ab_project_setup.ksh $(pwd) statement

Tags: unix, command, pwd

Please explain the meaning of this statement

```
. ./ab_project_setup.ksh $(pwd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to [Alberto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163336/please-explain-ab-project-setup-ksh-pwd-statement/4163363#4163363)'s answer:

Here is a small demo:

```
$ cat a.sh        # the script a.sh just exports a variable foo
export foo="$1"   # with it's value set to first command line argument.
$ echo $foo       # currently variable foo is not set.

$ . ./a.sh $(pwd) # source the script passing it pwd as argument.
$ echo $foo       # variable foo is now set.
/home/codaddict
$ pwd             # the present working directory.
/home/codaddict
```

Comment: `. ./a.sh $(pwd)` # source the script passing it the output of `pwd` as argument (not the text 'pwd')

Comment: $cat srihari.sh export srikanth="$1" $ksh -x srihari.sh $(pwd) + export srikanth=/home/examples/workbook1/srihari2010 $echo $srikanth --nothing displayed-- $. ./srihari.sh $(pwd) $echo $srikanth /home/examples/workbook1/srihari2010 $pwd /home/examples/workbook1/srihari2010 What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

```
.
```

means source what is following

```
./ab_project_setup.ksh
```

the name of the file you are sourcing

```
$(pwd)
```

expands to the current working directory and is passed as argument to the script.

Comment: thanks Alberto for your answer from your explanation i understood that $(pwd) is sent as an argument.How will we know whether the script expects argument and also why here in . ./script.ksh $(pwd) statement two dots are used?pls answer.

Comment: @srihari: to know if the script uses any parameter just open it and look inside, you should see a `$1` used; the first dot is to source, the second to specify that you want to use a file named `script.ksh` in the current directory.